# Submitting all items in a select input, even non-selected items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form, and the user needs to enter a list of email addresses that will receive a periodic report. I thought a good way to do this would be to have a text input, and buttons to add/remove and clear emails in select box. I used javascript to facilitate the buttons adding/removing and clearing the select box and this works fine. One thing I overlooked is that the select box only returns the selected items, however, in this case I want to return all of them.

Is there a way to return all of the items? One idea I had was to add a hidden input and just add the items in there as well.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, if you solve, contact me. Please!

Comment: I ended up using javascript to select everything in the select box just after you click the submit button. This feels kindof hacky but seems to work fine.